# Deployment of Virtual Assistant vs CoreBot template code

Tags: botframework

Noticed that **CoreBot 3.1** solution (with botframework 4.15+) can be deployed to both **Single Tenant and MultiTenant**, can the Virtual Assistant template be deployed to Single Tenant (app type)?

Have been trying to connect the **Azure Bot with Single Tenant** to App Service (**VA Bot**), it is keep failing with auth issues, whereas MultiTenant option works like charm.

Also, Is MSFT recommending not to use VA templates any chance as **VA and Skill templates** packages have been removed (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.VirtualAssistantTemplate) already?

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you do not use Virtual Assistant for new bots anymore, as it has essentially been deprecated.

Single Tenant is a fairly new app type that lets you restrict a bot to a specific Azure AD. It was never designed to work with VA.